# Div text selector without p tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a selector for the text within this div without wrapping it in a `<p>` tag or is possible with jquery / javascript to find all the text and wrap it in a `<p>` tag?

```html
<div class="content">
Some content in here.
<img src="image" alt="image" />
</div>
```

I cannot apply additional HTML markup and want to style the text differently to the image.

I would like either to wrap the text with `<p>` to become:

```html
<div class="content">
<p>Some content in here.</p>
<img src="image" alt="image" />
</div>
```

Or can I style it somehow with CSS selecting just the text without HTML markup?

Comment: You would be easier off changing the HTML markup.

Comment: do u mean you need the pure text inside the div with out the markup?

Comment: If the div contains multiple text nodes would you expect each of them to be wrapped in a paragraph?

Comment: I will have to look up text nodes I'm not sure what they mean. But if you are referring to multiple blocks of text then yes. Yes there is no way to add HTML markup to the text so I can't select it via traditional CSS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select all "bare text" (which are *text nodes*) with `.contents`, after which you should filter using `.nodeType === 3` (filtering out text nodes, which have a `nodeType` of 3).

E.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAYD2/.

```
$("div").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap("<p>");
```

You can then use CSS to style all `<p>` elements, for example.

Comment: Fantastic! I will look more text nodes. Thank you pimvdb.